# Keeping track of user role's

Tags: php

I created this class to keep track of a user's role:

```
class UserRoleHelper extends AppHelper
{
    public $helpers = array('Session');

    private $role = NULL;

    const CUSTOMER  = 'customer';
    const ASSOCIATE = 'associate';
    const MANAGER   = 'manager';
    const ADMIN     = 'admin';
    const DEVELOPER = 'developer';

    private $score = array(
        self::CUSTOMER  => 0,
        self::ASSOCIATE => 1,
        self::MANAGER   => 2,
        self::ADMIN     => 3,
        self::DEVELOPER => 4,
    );

    public function role()
    {
        if($this->role == NULL)
        {
            $this->role = strtolower($this->Session->read('Auth.User.role')) ?: 'customer';
        }
        return $this->role;
    }

    private function is($role)
    {
       return $this->score[$this->role()] >= $this->score[$role]; 
    }

    public function admin()
    {
        return $this->is(self::ADMIN);
    }

    public function manager()
    {
        return $this->is(self::MANAGER);
    }

    public function associate()
    {
        return $this->is(self::ASSOCIATE);
    }

}
```

The idea is to be able to have an expression like:

```
if($this->UserRole->manager())
{
    //do something
}
```

And have it evaluate true if you are a manager or higher (admin, developer).

I also tried to design it so if there is ever the need to add a level like GENERAL_MANGER = 3 which would shift the values of ADMIN and DEVELOPER up one, it won't effect anything.

I originally had the keys in the `$score` array as strings, but it seemed redundant when I had constants already defined with the same values. I have never seen an array definition with constants for keys in a class body before. I know variables are not allowed but it seems to work with constants. Still don't know if that is bad or not though.

Is there anything I have missed or can do to make this better?

Answer (score 2):

Use an [enumerator](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.splenum.php)?

And use it like this:

```
if($this->isInRole(Roles::MANAGER)
```

Comment: It's still considered experimental -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.spl-types.php

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine, the internal logic is encapsulated.

Maybe this number comparison based role logic will not work if you have VIP_CUSTOMER and VIP_MANAGER roles and VIP_MANAGER's can't manage non-VIP CUSTOMERs/functions and simple MANAGER's can't manager VIP_CUSTOMERs/functions. In this case you can change implementation without any change in the client code to support this.

(For example the VIP_MANAGER's score is 3 and MANAGER's score remains 2 then every VIP_MANAGER would be a MANAGER. If MANAGER's score is 3 and VIP_MANAGER's score is 2 then every MANAGER would be a VIP_MANAGER. None of them is good but you can modify the `manager` (and the imaginary `vipManager`) method to support this.
)

Changing the internal logic also a nice solution when the MANAGERs are not allowed to buy anything, so they shouldn't have the CUSTOMER role. You just change the `manager` method and it will work.